# Piece of code doesn't give the answer I need. Suggested edits?

Tags: c++, networking

This code is supposed to check the input array for five consecutive '1's if found, it is supposed to add a '0' at the end as a parity bit for a simple parity bit checker.

This is the code.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, a[30], b[5] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, temp = 0, count = 0;
    cout << "Enter the size of input bits :";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the input bits :";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i >= 4) {
            temp = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (a[temp] == b[j]) {
                    temp++;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (count == 4) {
        n = n + 1;
        a[n] = 0;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i];
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of c++ usage issues here. Don't use `conio.h` and remove `using namespace std`. You don't use anything from `stdio.h` so don't include it. Use the STL containers over the raw arrays.

Comment: You don't need to have an array of five `1` you could use a counter. When a `1` is found increment a counter, when other integer is found reset the counter to `0`. If the counter reach `5` anytime, add the `0` parity bit. By the way the code don't detect when the first five integer enter are `1`. This condition is wrong `if (i >= 4)`

Comment: Doesn't this question belong on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple logic of what you want to achieve.. let's say input array is `a`, it's length is `n`:

```
int counter = 0;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if(a[i] == 1)
        counter++;

    else
        counter = 0; //need to start looking for 1's again because consecutive stream is broken

    if(counter == 5) {
        a[i+1] = 0;   //found 5 consecutive 1's so next bit will be 0
        i++;          //don't need to check the next bit which is already 0
        counter = 0;  //resetting counter
    }
}
```

The above code will change the array `[2,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,5]` to -> `[2,3,1,1,1,1,1,0,4,5]`

If you want to insert `0` at the end of the array then simply change `a[i+1] = 0` to `a[n+1] = 0` and remove `i++;`

You also need to make sure that `n` is not greater than the size of array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I was looking more in terms of a binary code. If the input array was something like {1,1,1,,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1}, the count will exceed 5.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go line by line from the beginning:

1. change `for(int i=n; i>=0; i--)` to `for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)` (n-sized array in C++ has cells in the range of [0, n-1])
2. change `if(i>=4)` to `if (n >= 5)`
3. place `temp++` after `if(a[temp]==b[j]){}`, not inside of it.
4. add

   ```
   if (count == 5) break;
   else count = 0;
   ```

   just after `for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)` loop
5. change

   ```
    if(count==4)
    {
        n=n+1;
        a[n]=0;
    }
   ```

   to

   ```
   if(count == 5){
     a[n] = 0;
     n = n+1;
   }
   ```

   Once again! n-sized array holds n elements on positions 0 to n-1
   Of course sequence makes a difference above!
   You can also write it as `if (count == 5) a[n++] = 0;`

   And that would be all.